Book series involving a boy and a girl who use a ring or rings to travel to other universes and time periods to stop a bad guy
I need help identifying a book series (four books or more) which I read in middle/high school (2013-2019).
In the beginning, there was a kid who played a sport (I think basketball) and people were disappearing from the town.  Then his dad/uncle (not sure which) came into the picture and presented him with a ring which helped open portals to different universes, all where he had to stop a bad guy from doing something.  It was the boy and a girl who had a ring or two rings, and they went to places like in a jungle, underwater, in the past, etc. etc.  They had to prevent the blimp from going down, then eventually had to make sure the blimp went down due to it being an important point in history.  They had to prevent him poisoning the water or the food.
I would greatly appreciate the help as this is driving me wild and I want to read these books again.

This sounds like the Pendragon series by D.J. McHale, which I've proposed as an answer to a different question before.

The series chronicles the adventures of Bobby Pendragon, an American teenager who discovers that he must travel through time and space to prevent the destruction of the ten "territories": critical times and locations throughout the universe.

The main character, Bobby, is indeed a basketball player on Earth before his uncle takes him through a portal to another territory. The portals through which the characters travel are in fixed locations, but Bobby uses a pair of basically small ring portals to send journals of his adventures back to his friends on Earth.
There are adventures in the jungle, on a water planet, and one that involves trying to stop the destruction of the Hindenburg in Earth's past.
